# Musixtex end of line bar problem

Tags: musixtex

I have an issue with some bars at end of line (see image).
As you can see on the second line, it not happens at every lines.

Do you have any idea why does this happens ? (part of the code below)

Thanks,

LoloDf

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,twoside,inner=1.7cm,outer=1.5cm,top=0.4cm,bottom=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage[frenchb]{babel}
\title{\vspace*{-0.2cm}Waltz Nr. 10 in h-moll\\Op. 69,2 (Posth)}
\date{}
\nobarnumbers
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\normalmusicsize
\begin{flushright}
F. Chopin\\
1810-1849
\end{flushright}
\hspace*{0.7cm}\textbf{Moderato\newline}
\begin{music}
\instrumentnumber{1}%2instruments
\setstaffs1{2}%instrument1(enbas):2portées
\setclef{1}{60}%clefdefa(6)en1,clefdesol(0)en2
\generalsignature{2}%
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{3}{4}}%mesure3/4
\def\qpl{\raise3\Interligne\soupir}
\def\qpu{\raise2\Interligne\qp}
\startpiece
\Notes\soupir|\zchar{15}{4}\isluru0m\isluru1n\usf{10}\qa{m}\enotes
\bar\Notes\cmidstaff{\p}\pdld\qa{I}\sk\zql{Mb}\ql d\sk\zql{Mb}\ql d\pdlu|\tslur0m\ibl0j{-1}\qb0{m}\qb0{nm}\uptext{2}\qb0{j}\uptext{3}\qb0{k}\tbl0\zchar{12}{1}\qb0i\enotes
\bar\Notes\pdld\qa{J}\sk\zql{Mc}\ql e\sk\zql{Mc}\ql e\pdlu|\uptext{2}\midslur{5}\tslur1h\ha{^h}\sk\sk\sk\isluru0m\zchar{15}{4}\isluru1n\usf{10}\qa{m}\enotes
\bar\Notes\pdld\qa{^H}\sk\zql{M^a}\ql e\sk\zql{Ma}\ql e\pdlu|\tslur0m\ibl0j{-1}\qb0{m}\qb0{n}\qb0{m}\uptext{2}\qb0{j}\uptext{4}\qb0{l}\zchar{12}{3}\tbl0\qb0k\enotes
\bar\Notes\pdld\qa{I}\sk\zql{Mb}\ql d\sk\zql{Mb}\ql d\pdlu|\midslur{5}\tslur1i\uptext{1}\ha{i}\sk\sk\sk\isluru0m\isluru1n\zchar{15}{2}\usf{10}\qa{m}\enotes
\bar\Notes\pdld\zchar{14}{\crescendo{23mm}}\qa{I}\sk\zql{Mb}\ql d\sk\zql{Mb}\ql d\pdlu|\tslur0m\ibl0j{1}\qb0{m}\zchar{11}{3}\qb0{n^lm}\zchar{14}{4}\qb0{p}\tbl0\zchar{15}{5}\qb0r\tslur1u\enotes
\vspace*{0.2mm}\alaligne\Notes\pdld\qa{I}\sk\zql{^Nb}\ql d\sk\zql{Nb}\ql d\pdlu|\isluru1r\tslur1r\qa{r}\sk\isluru1m\qa{^l}\sk\tslur1r\isluru1r\qa{r}\enotes
\bar\Notes\pdld\qa{I}\sk\zql{=Nb}\ql e\sk\zql{Nb}\ql e\pdlu|\tslur1r\qa{r}\sk\isluru1m\qa{=l}\sk\isluru0q\usf{14}\zchar{19}{4}\qa{q}\enotes
[HERE A LOT OF OTHER LINES....but I cut to make it clear]
\Endpiece
\end{music}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. I love music, but is there `\endpiece` or `\Endpiece` at the end after `\startpiece`?

Comment: Hello, it's an \Endpiece, the whole code was too long to put here :) I'll edit adding more details

Comment: You are welcome always here. Positive vote for entering the full code and for the effort made.

Comment: There is a curious fact: if I remove the `[HERE...]` part and comment out the call to `geometry`, the sequence `pdflatex-musixflx-pdflatex` produces *very* bad output. This makes me think there's an input error somewhere.

Comment: What do you mean by bad output ? can you show the output ? (I don't have latex on the laptop I use right know...maybe the bad output is due to the cut I made in the code...)

Comment: And why commenting geometry ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [user's guide](https://ctan.org/pkg/musixtex?lang=en) declares it's important to handle blank lines within the input files.

Here, however, you should keep a blank before your beginning of the input.

```
\end{flushright}
\hspace*{0.7cm}\textbf{Moderato\newline} 

\begin{music}
\instrumentnumber{1}%2instruments
```

[image]

Comment: And `\newline` does nothing useful.