# MusiXTEX line width and bar lines problem

Tags: musixtex

I am trying to rewrite a simple piece of melody in MusixTEX. The problem is that bar lines and end line width does not automatically align the way they're supposed to.
[image: The problem, lines and bar does not align correctly]

I want them to be aligned like this:

[image: How I want it to be formatted]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{musixtex}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{music}%
\elemskip%    
\normalmusicsize%
\instrumentnumber{1}%
\nobarnumbers%
\setstaffs1{1}%
\generalmeter{\meterfrac{4}4}%
\generalsignature{5}%
\parindent0pt%
\startpiece%
\NOtes\Dqbl{k}{j}\en\NOTesp\hup{g}\en\bar%
\NOtes\Dqbl{k}{j}\en\NOTesp\hup{g}\en\bar%
\NOtes\Dqbl{k}{j}\en\NOTesp\hup{g}\en\bar%
\NOTEs\pause\en\bar%
\NOtes\Dqbu{d}{c}\en\NOTesp\hup{N}\en\bar%
\NOtes\Dqbu{d}{c}\en\NOTes\hu{N}\en\NOtes\Dqbu{a}{b}\en\bar%
\NOtes\Dqbu{d}{c}\en\NOTes\ha{N}\en\bar%
\Endpiece%
\end{music}%
\end{document}
```

I have followed the instructions to compile accoringly to the MusiXTEX manual (http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/CTAN/macros/musixtex/doc/musixdoc.pdf#page.145) and my compile script is:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
# tex file is main.tex

latex main.tex
musixtex  -l -x main
latex main.tex
makeindex main
latex main.tex
latex main.tex
dvips -e0 main
ps2pdf main.ps

rm -f *.aux
rm -f *.ps
rm -f *.dvi
rm -f *.idx
rm -f *.ilg
rm -f *.ind
rm -f *.mx1
rm -f *.mx2
rm -f *.log
rm -f *.toc
rm -f *.bbl
rm -f *.blg
rm -f *.out
rm -f make/bib
```

I have tried several solutions, none of which has been working:

1. [MusiXTex problem with musixflx](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/447283/musixtex-problem-with-musixflx)
2. [Musixtex end of line bar problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/439335/musixtex-end-of-line-bar-problem)
3. [Harmonize width of MusiXTex extracts automatically](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/479943/harmonize-width-of-musixtex-extracts-automatically)

I have been extra careful to not have any spaces after the end of each line, hence the "%". I do not know where the problem lies not how to fix it. Any help is appreciated!.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The manual describes this issue on page 6. There an example is given of unevenly spaced music, followed by *After running `musixflx` and TEX-ing the second time you'll get:* and then an image of evenly spaced music. The compile sequence is described in more detail on the previous page, stating that there is a three pass compilation sequence: `etex jobname`, `musixflx jobname` and `etex jobname` again. Substituting `etex` for `pdflatex` I get the following compile sequence and result on your MWE:

```
pdflatex testfile.tex
musixflx testfile
pdflatex testfile.tex
```

[image]

Note that the extra bar line in the last bar is not supposed to be present, I have removed the `\bar` in your code to remove the line from the output.